# connect between Auth User data and collection in Firestore with flutter

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I have used phone Auth with flutter and firebase, and I completed login and insert user information which is just (`id`, `phone`, `displayName`) and all this information exists in Auth, without the need to create a collection in Firestore.

Now I have created a collection in Firestore for tasks, for example, therefore every user should have many tasks.

How can I make a connection between the user from authentication, and the tasks collection from Firestore?

Can I make it without creating a user collection and using the user from auth or not?

```
 onPressed: () {
   if(taskTitleInputController.text.isNotEmpty && taskDescripInputController.text.isNotEmpty) {
     Firestore.instance.collection("users").document(widget.uid).collection("tasks")
    .add({
      'title' : taskTitleInputController.text,
      'desc' : taskDescripInputController.text
      ).then((result)=>Navigator.pop(context));
    }
 })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you shared shows that you have a data model where you store the tasks for a user in a subcollection under that user's document. This is a valid and common way of modeling such data.

An alternative would be to have a global task list, so with a single top-level `tasks` collection. In that case you'd need to store the UID of the user owning the task in each task document.

Both models are valid and common, and neither is pertinently better than the other. As usual with NoSQL databases, the correct model depends on the use-cases of your specific app, and you'll likely have to adapt the data model as you discover/add more use-cases.